# addEventListener for 'this'

Tags: javascript

For example we have Events in HTML like this:

```
<div onclick="bla(this)" class="gg">
```

How could we  add an Event Listener/Handler to all the gg elements by not writing the `onclick="bla(this)"` thing in HTML?

I've tried something like this. But of course it does not work.

```
var ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for (var i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++) {
// the 'this' below needs to go somewhere to become working
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click',bla,this); 
}
```

**EDIT**: The original code works http://jsfiddle.net/pVpaV/2/ . To make the code to work I need to put it at the end of the page.

Comment: `bla` will be called in the context of the `gg` element by default, you don't need to pass it as a param.

Comment: @zzzzBov Not in OP's case, since he's invoking the handler via the `"onclick"` attribute...

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem now? None of the answers are correct? You can't properly state your question? You can't copy-paste correctly? What is it?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I'd been referring to the part where `bla` was being passed to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep using `bla` as it was originally, you'll need to wrap it and pass the appropriate parameter:

```
var ggs,
    i;
ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for (i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++) {
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        //in the event handler, `this` refers to the clicked element
        bla(this);
    }, false);
}
```

If you simply need to call `bla` in the context of the element that triggered the event, `addEventListener` *already does that by default*.

```
var ggs,
    i;
function bla(e) {
    //`e` is event data
    //`this` is the element that triggered the event
}
ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for (i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++) {
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', bla, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is handle `click` events on divs that have the class `gg`

jQuery can do this quite easily

```
$('.gg').click(function() {
// some code you want to execute on click
});
```

You can check out the jQuery class selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

With just javascript (although support for `getElementsByClassName` is [limited](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)):

```
var ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for (var i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++)
{
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', function() { bla(this); }, true);
}
function bla(param)
{
    // some very sinister code that uses this (which is param in this context)
    alert(param);
}
```

Comment: They're after pure JS, but this is the easiest meyhod

Answer (score 1):

your code should work fine provided you have a function called bla

http://jsfiddle.net/pVpaV/

One thing to note is that some versions of IE use a legacy method called attachEvent(). Which browser are you using?

Comment: I don't understand why it does not work for me (last Chrome)... Wondering

Answer (score 0):

```
var ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for(var i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++) {
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', bla);
}
```

The element is automatically passed as `this` when using `addEventListener`. Note that you actually need to use `this` inside the function - it's not an argument. If you do want an argument the easiest and most portable way is this one:

```
var ggs = document.getElementsByClassName('gg');
for(var i = 0; i < ggs.length; i++) {
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        bla(this);
    });
}
```

However, in this case you cannot access the event object passed to the function by the browser unless you pass it as an additional argument:

```
    ggs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        bla(this, e);
    });
```

Comment: No, he wants the target element as a first argument of `bla`; the event handler is bound to the target element by default, so no need to do anything extra to achieve what you do so explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the MDN article about it first.

Comment: Your second and third code blocks will not work correctly, as the event handlers will execute after the entire `for` loop has finished and `i` will be equal to `ggs.length` regardless of which element is clicked. There is really no need to reference `ggs[i]`, since `this` in the handler is already a reference to the same element and you can use it directly.

Comment: oops, gotcha. Funny how I answered lots of questions where the OP had exactly that problem and then stumbled into it myself...